# how to pass the new old identifier with userenv from dual table in postgres trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I convert oracle scripting to  PostgreSQL which requires the user to update the last login information in Oracle trigger this I used:

```
if inserting then 
:new.last_update := sysdate
select osuser into :new.updated_by from gv@session where audsid =
(select userenv('sessionid') from dual);
end if;
```

how can I covert to postgres?  I get stuck after the select ... from dual and dual is not a table in postgres.

```
if TG_OP = 'INSERT' then
new.last_update :=current_timestamp;
SELECT usename INTO :new.update_by
FROM pg_user
WHERE usesysid = (SELECT ..(I got stuck here)
RETURN NEW;
END IF;
```

how to get the trigger function would work properly with dual table?

Comment: The `(select userenv('sessionid') from dual)` was useless in Oracle to begin with and could have been simplified to `where audsid = userenv('sessionid');`

Comment: not sure the trigger works or not, but so far its created w/o error
if TG_OP = 'INSERT' then
new.last_update :=current_timestamp;
SELECT usename INTO :new.update_by
FROM pg_user
WHERE usesysid = (SELECT .userenv('sessionid'));
end ifl
RETURN NEW;
END IF;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lets clear up the `dual` issue. Oracle syntax required completion of the FROM clause. When there is no actual table not a sub-select, dual is used to complete the required syntax. Postgres does not require the completion of the FROM clause. The following is the same query.

```
      Oracle:                          Postgres:      
      Select 'abc' from dual;          Select 'abc';
```

Your other issue, well looks like you are out of luck. In Oracle the variable `OSUSER` is the user on the client (through Oracle Client - OCI) even if that is not the same userid used to sign-in to the database. **Postgres however does not make this available**.

Comment: I did yesterday, 
SELECT usename INTO :new.update_by FROM pg_user WHERE usesysid = (SELECT .userenv('sessionid'); and the trigger created. T